# Is touchstart and touchend required to develop a game for a ios, android ect.?

Tags: javascript, android, ios, html, cordova

I am in the middle of developing an `html5` game. I have been using the `mousedown` and `mouseup` event handlers for `touch events`. I have recently been trying to migrate it to a `phone emulator` to see how it preforms on a `device`. I was wondering if I needed to rewrite all of my events that use `mousedown` and up to `touchstart` and `touchend` ect. events. The `mousedown` and `mouseup` listeners seem to be working fine while I play my game while the "**Emulate touch screen**" setting is on. In terms of performance is there a reason to use one over the other?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you should change to `touch` events. Although the `mouse` events also work on mobile browser, there is a well-known [300ms click delay](http://www.telerik.com/blogs/what-exactly-is.....-the-300ms-click-delay) on mobile device. Considering that you are developing HTML5 game, it's worthy for you to improve the performance.

There are some third party library such as [jQuery Mobile](https://api.jquerymobile.com/vclick/) which may help you to mask the event for easier development.